# Shared library: break the ABI compatibility without breaking API compatibility

Tags: c, api, shared-libraries, abi

Is it possible, for a pure C shared library, to break the ABI compatibility while API compatibility is not broken?

Also, if one writes a library A which provides all the API functions of an existing library B, with some additional API functions, is library A ABI compatible with library B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have different calling conventions in two libraries implementing the same API, if that answers your first question.

For the second question: You could change e.g. a structure pointer to a pointer to another structure in the declaration of a function. According to the standard they have to have the same representation and alignment requirements, but the API is changed (and code calling that function of A must be changed to call the same function in B in order to compile).

Answer (score 1):

First question: If by "API compatibility" you mean source compatibility, changing the calling convention, or the contents of user-defined types, will do this.

Second question: It probably depends on the platform or compilation options, but it can be.